# Format for writing an email accepting the job offered by the company?

Tags: new-job, email, first-job, job-acceptance

I have received an e-mail from a company that is offering me a job. I need to accept that letter in order to confirm the job. Since this is the first time I am writing such an e-mail I am really confused about the SUBJECT and the contents of the e-mail that states the acceptance of the job offered by the company.

I googled but all I can find is the format of acceptance letters, not an e-mail.

Comment: So, use the acceptance letter format. If you have a *specific* issue with that, ask here. Your question is attracting 'close votes' because it is too broad: as it is now, you're essentially asking us to do the work, and that is not how StackExchange sites work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not a difficult task.

Subject: Job offer

Body:

Dear Sir or Madam,

I am delighted to accept the job offer you recently made to me.

I look forward to starting work on . Please let me know of any documentation you need me to supply, or any activities I need to complete prior to starting.

Yours sincerely,

Codefreak.

Comment: +1, but worth adding that if you reply to the email offer, the subject should be automatically generated (e.g. Re: job offer)

Answer (score 2):

Did you already discuss pay, benefits or otherwise negotiate the terms of the offer? If so, a basic acceptance as provided by [TrueDub](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/33865/25739) is fine. Otherwise, your mail should confirm that you're still interested in the position and would like to schedule a meeting to discuss the terms of the offer.

You don't want to jump the gun and accept their offer right out, assuming you're from a culture where negotiation an offer is common.